# Connect to database depending on host

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect to my database depending if I'm on localhost or on the webapp that's hosted online. But I don't know how to do that. Anyone got some idea's or examples?

Because now I have to comment out my line of code everytime I'm deploying my web app to the host and use the database credentials for the online host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Inspect the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) superglobal and check if the code is running locally.

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] === "127.0.0.1") {
  // Running on local development server
}
```

2) Set and read environment variable that identifies where the code is running

In `.htaccess`

```
SetEnv MY_ENVIRONMENT "live"
```

In code:

```
<?php 
if (get_env("MY_ENVIRONMENT") === "live") {
  // Running in live environment
}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to include the IPV6 version of localhost too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$local = [
    'www.example.devlocal'
];

if (!in_array($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $local)) {
      // Development server
} else {
      //Local server
}
```

Or you can also detect by IP address of the server:

```
$whitelist = array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1'
);

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist)){
    // This is production server
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to only store the database credentials in the specific environment on which they are supposed to be used.

So you could create a `db.credentials.php` file on both the local and remote servers. The contents of which would be respectively different, but something like this:

```
<?php
$databasename = "myDB";
$username = "me";
$password = "C0mpl3x P@55w0rd";
```

Then you simply source that file in your php code:

```
require_once("path/to/db.credentials.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the server name to see if it's local host with something like:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "localhost")
  $database_credentials = "local";
else
  $database_credentials = "remote";
```